# How do I avoid duplicating spring <task:scheduled ...>?

Tags: java, spring

Consider the following snippet of the applicationContext.xml:

```
<task:scheduler id="xfsXmlProducer" pool-size="1" />

<task:scheduler id="xfsXmlConsumer" pool-size="${transactionqueue.consumerThreadsCount}" />

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="xfsXmlProducer">
    <task:scheduled ref="xmlFileProducerJob" method="run" fixed-delay="3000"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="xfsXmlConsumer">
    <task:scheduled ref="xmlFileConsumerJob" method="run" fixed-delay="10"/>
    <task:scheduled ref="xmlFileConsumerJob" method="run" fixed-delay="10"/>
    <task:scheduled ref="xmlFileConsumerJob" method="run" fixed-delay="10"/>
    <task:scheduled ref="xmlFileConsumerJob" method="run" fixed-delay="10"/>
    <task:scheduled ref="xmlFileConsumerJob" method="run" fixed-delay="10"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<bean id="xmlFileConsumerJob"
      class="xxxx.parser.job.XmlFileConsumerJob"
      lazy-init="true"
      scope="prototype"/>

<bean id="xmlFileProducerJob"
      class="xxxx.parser.job.XmlFileProducerJob" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="transactionBulkSize" value="${transactionqueue.bulkSize}" />
</bean>
```

Is there any way to avoid duplicating

```
<task:scheduled ref="xmlFileConsumerJob" method="run" fixed-delay="10"/>
```

?

I'd like just to specify number of workers.

Comment: do you want to run the same task 5 times?

Comment: I want to run the same task in 5 threads. Every worker task takes an object from queue and process it.

Comment: hmm if you already have a worker, why would you use the scheduler? simply create a threadpool and run your worker with it

Comment: The idea is to periodically run worker as spring task, which tries to get object from queue. After some timeout, if queue is empty, task finishes and reexecuted by spring scheduler. This allows me to avoid `while (true)` loops in worker's code. The configuration above allows me to have 5 workers running simultaneously.

Comment: i think you should start the worker by scheduler, but let the worker create threads and execute the tasks